# How to use CAST to return date column with just month and day

Tags: sql-server, casting

Using a CAST function in a select statement, how do I return a date column with just the month and day?

```
SELECT CAST(DateAdded as date) -- returns column with date format
, CAST(DateAdded as time) -- returns only time
, CAST(DateAdded as ...) --return only month and day
```

Comment: `return only month and day`, in what format?, `DD-MM`?, `MM-DD`?, `DD/MM`?, etc

Comment: Format doesn't matter as much as using a CAST function to output it in such a way as to provide Month and Day. For the sake of this example, format to MM/DD.

Comment: SELECT   concat(month(cast(Dateadded as time)), '/', day(cast(dateadded as time))) is something I thought of, but is there a more elegant way to use the CAST function?

Comment: `MONTH(CAST(column as TIME))`??, Besides, if you are gonna use `MONTH` then you simply don't need `CAST` at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this(replacing the getdate function with your date column):

```
select
cast(getdate() as date) as FullDate
, right(cast(getdate() as date),5) as MonthDay
, cast(getdate() as time) as TimeofDay
```

Warning: this may depend on which version of SQL Server you are using.

Comment: This works and also led me to 'select cast(getdate() as varchar(5)) as MonthDay'

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), GETDATE(), 4)
21.10
```

OR

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), GETDATE(), 5) 
21-10
```

OR

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), GETDATE(), 3) 

21/10
```

OR

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),MONTH(GETDATE())) + '-'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),DAY(GETDATE()))

 10-21
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this using a CAST function, not CONVERT?

Comment: The Convert function allows you to pass the third optional parameters for `Style` you dont have this option in cast function, cast function will always return something like `Oct 21 2015.....` , Yes in the last option you can use either it will not make a difference.

Comment: Yes, I know how to do this using the convert function, but this is an exercise question that requires using the CAST function.